# Padding or margin for CEWP

Tags: css, html, cewp

I have added a link to another page via a CEWP but I need to move the position of the link to the top of the web part.  I have attached a screenshot which will demonstrate the issue better.  I need the link below the grey line of the previous webpart.[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ductape patch is adding a negative margin-top

```
<div style="margin-top:-200px">
 YOUR CONTENT
</div>
```